# Webpack does not replace images in HTML files

Tags: webpack

I'm using Webpack with Angular 2 app. Loaders in My Webpack config file looks like below. I removed plugins and imports to avoid lengthy sample code. Webpack is replacing images in css files with hashed names but not from html files. Not sure what I am missing. Will appreciate any pointers.

```
module.exports = function (options) {
    const DATAS = {
        VERSION: JSON.stringify(require("../package.json").version),
        DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: options.env === 'dev'
    };
    return {
        entry: {
            'polyfills': './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
            'global': './src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css',
            'main': './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
            modules: ['node_modules']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, loader: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery' },
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    loaders: [
                        'angular2-template-loader',
                        'awesome-typescript-loader'
                    ],
                    exclude: ['node_modules/generator-jhipster']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    loader: 'raw-loader',
                    exclude: ['./src/main/webapp/index.html']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
                    exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
                },
                {
                    test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
                    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/i,
                    loaders: [
                        'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                        'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /app.constants.ts$/,
                    loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
                        replacements: [{
                            pattern: /\/\* @toreplace (\w*?) \*\//ig,
                            replacement: function (match, p1, offset, string) {
                                return `_${p1} = ${DATAS[p1]};`;
                            }
                        }]
                    })
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `raw-loader` for the HTML files, which just gives you a string without any processing. Instead you want to use `html-loader` which does exactly what you want. Change the `.html` rule to:

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  loader: 'html-loader',
  exclude: ['./src/main/webapp/index.html']
},
```

Comment: I did exact same thing based on another SO answer. I'm getting errors like below when I use html-loader `ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/account/password-reset/init/password-reset-init.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html-loader' in '/Users/company/folder/myapp'
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/account/password-reset/init/password-reset-init.component.ts 46:18-65
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/account/index.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/account/account.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts` and more code.

Comment: You need to install `html-loader` with `npm install --save-dev html-loader`

Comment: I am using webpack for first time and assumed wepack would load the module from its library. I literally wasted al least 2 days on this trying several things. Thanks a lot.